# como executar eprimer3 via terminal e através de biopython? não há um problema com o código, mas sim com o comando eprimer3. Sugestões?

Tags: python

neemias@debian:/$ python

Python 2.7.9 (default, Aug 13 2016, 16:41:35)

[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

import Bio

from Bio.Emboss.Applications import Primer3Commandline

from Bio.Emboss import Primer3

cl = Primer3Commandline()

cl.set_parameter("-sequence", "/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/seq1.fasta")

cl.set_parameter("-outfile", "/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/out.pr3")

cl.set_parameter("-numreturn", 1)

Primer3Commandline(cmd='eprimer3', outfile='/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/out.pr3', sequence='/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/seq1.fasta', numreturn=1)

print cl

eprimer3 -outfile=/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/out.pr3 -sequence=/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/seq1.fasta -numreturn=1

import os

os.system(str(cl))

Pick PCR primers and hybridization oligos

Error: Missing SEQUENCE tag

0

quit()

(NÃO FUNCIONA NO PYTHON)

neemias@debian:/$ eprimer3 -outfile=/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/out.pr3 -sequence=/home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/seq1.fasta -numreturn=1

Pick PCR primers and hybridization oligos

Error: Missing SEQUENCE tag

(NÃO FUNCIONA NO TERMINAL)

neemias@debian:/$ EMBOSS_PRIMER32_CORE=/usr/bin/primer3_core eprimer32 -sequence /home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/seq1.fasta -stdout /home/neemias/Documentos/google_drive/agronomia/python/primer.out

Pick PCR primers and hybridization oligos

(FUNCIONA NO TERMINAL)